# Best way to insert multiple rows in mysql with c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to input mutiple rows of data into this MySQL using C#.
[image]

I have this code below for inserting one row, but I am not sure how to approach multiple rows at once. I need to input a maximum of 8 rows into the table. Should i make multiple constructors or is there a better way?

```
public class Vo2phases
{
    //properties for vo2max phases
    public int VO2TestID { get; set; }
    public int Phase { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public int Intensity { get; set; }
    public double RER { get; set; }
    public int Borgscale { get; set; }
    public int Pulse { get; set; }

    public Vo2phases(int _vo2testid, int _phase, 
                     DateTime _time, int _intensity, 
                     double _rer, int _borgscale, int _pulse)
    {
        //set parameters for phases
        VO2TestID = _vo2testid;
        Phase = _phase;
        Time = _time;
        Intensity = _intensity;
        RER = _rer;
        Borgscale = _borgscale;
        Pulse = _pulse;
    }

    public void addToDB()
    {
        try
        {
            //prepare for query
            var cmd = MySQL.readyQuery();

            //insert testdata to Vo2test
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vo2phases_tb (Vo2_TestID, Phase, Time, Intensity, RER, Borgscale, Pulse) VALUES (@Vo2testid, @phase, @time, @intensity, @rer, @borgscale, @pulse);";

            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vo2testid", VO2TestID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phase", Phase);
            string TimeString = "00:" + Convert.ToString(Time.TimeOfDay.Hours) + ":" + Convert.ToString(Time.TimeOfDay.Minutes);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", TimeString);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intensity", Intensity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rer", RER);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borgscale", Borgscale);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pulse", Pulse);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.Connection.Close();
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you only seem to be expecting 1 Vo2phase in your code.

While this isn't a problem in concept or even in execution, it is lacking because it doesn't account for a collection being submitted.

I would overload `addToDB` so that it accepts a List as a parameter.

```
public void addToDB(List<Vo2phase> phases)
{
    try
    {
        //prepare for query
        var cmd = MySQL.readyQuery();

        //insert testdata to Vo2test
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO vo2phases_tb (Vo2_TestID, Phase, Time, Intensity, RER, Borgscale, Pulse) VALUES (@Vo2testid, @phase, @time, @intensity, @rer, @borgscale, @pulse);";

        cmd.Prepare();
        foreach (Vo2phase phase in phases)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vo2testid", VO2TestID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phase", Phase);
            string TimeString = "00:" + Convert.ToString(Time.TimeOfDay.Hours) + ":" + Convert.ToString(Time.TimeOfDay.Minutes);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@time", TimeString);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intensity", Intensity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rer", RER);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@borgscale", Borgscale);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pulse", Pulse);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Now to build the list, you'd simply add in a whole bunch of Vo2phases:

```
List<Vo2phase> Phases = new List<Vo2phase>
{
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...),
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...),
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...),
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...),
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...),
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...),
    new Vo2phase(VO2TestID = testId, Phase = i ...)

    // add the parameters as you normally would.
};
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My approach, if I was expecting a high volume of inserts, would be to make the `addToDB` a static method that takes a connection and a collection of `Vo2phases`; you pretty much lose any benefit to, and actually incur some cost from, `prepare` when you only use it for single command executions.

Barring that, the prepared command could be maintained as a static member variable so that it is not recreated constantly; however, then you'd probably devote some code to verifying that command has not "gone bad" since it was last used.